# When trying to run this below code not getting as expected results

Tags: python-3.x

```
def abc(num):
    while num !=1:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = num / 2
            print(num)
            abc(num)
        else:
            num = num * 3 + 1
            print(num)
            abc(num)
    else:
        print('You have achieved 1')
z=int(input('Enter the number:-'))
abc(z)

Expected Output :
Lets say we enter number 3
10
5.0
16.0
8.0
4.0
2.0
1.0
You have achieved 1

Real output:
Enter the number:-3
10
5.0
16.0
8.0
4.0
2.0
1.0
You have achieved 1
You have achieved 1
1.0
You have achieved 1
You have achieved 1
2.0
1.0
You have achieved 1
You have achieved 1
1.0
You have achieved 1
You have achieved 1
4.0
2.0
1.0
You have achieved 1
You have achieved 1
1.0
You have achieved 1
You have achieved 1
2.0
1.0
You have achieved 1
You have achieved 1
1.0
You have achieved 1
You have achieved 1
8.0
4.0
2.0
1.0
You have achieved 1
You have achieved 1
```

when i am runing this code i expect the code to end when the number comes down to 1 but after coming down to 1,the else part runs twice and again the NUM value increases by 1 and it again enters the while loop.Can anyone please explain this.I tried debugging but still can not figure out how the NUM value is increasing after  reaching down to 1.

- List item

Comment: While in the while loop, you are calling the `abc` function again. So, it will run again, causing this 'weird' behaviour. Just stop calling `abc` recursively.

Comment: but i want to understand how will it enter while loop once it reaches 1?

Comment: When the while-loop finally reaches `1` it will have already called the function `abc` multiple times. When that happens, that specific loop will then terminate, and then all other while-loops will continue their respective loops in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `abc()` inside `abc()`. You already have a `while` loop - no need to recurse.

```
def abc(num): 

    while num !=1:         # this loop works until num == 1 then it prints else part
        print(num)             # print the current number 
        if num % 2 == 0:          
            num = num / 2 
        else:
            num = num * 3 + 1 
    else:
        print(num)            # print the 1
        print('You have achieved 1')

z=int(input('Enter the number: '))
abc(z)                    # here you call the function with its initial value
```

After you recurse into `abc()` and it recurses and it recurses etc the one with num == 1 prints its achievement message then it returns to the calling `abc()` where it continues in its while loop with what was left as it's `num` *before* recursing.

Comment: Hi patrik from you explanation i understood that i should not call the function when the condition is already recursing in while loop.But still i   cannot understand how will it enter while loop  to call the function once it reaches 1?Could you please explain

Comment: @Shub you only call the function _**once**_ - after your input() statement. The function runs until num is 1 in the while loop, then it prints the whiles else: part. - Recursing means : calling the same function you are in with some other parameter - this function is not recursing, it is looping using a while loop